# Sorting MongoDB results using Spring Boot with MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, sorting, mongotemplate

**The goal**

I'd like to have this query:

```sh
db.getCollection("employees").find().sort({
  hire_date: 1
}).limit(10)
```

written with MongoTemplate in Spring Boot.

**The research**

I've seen many posts and sites about sorting like e.g.

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-mongodb-aggregations
- [Spring + MongoDB - MongoTemplate + Criteria Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018869/spring-mongodb-mongotemplate-criteria-query)
- [Spring MongoDB query sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521009/spring-mongodb-query-sorting)

**Attempts**

I've tried many ways but I still can't figure out how can I have this done. Some of the things I've tried are listed below:

```java
@Service
public class MongoService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public Document simpleQuery() {

        // 1st
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                sort(Sorts.ascending("hire_date")),
                limit(10)
        ));

        // 2nd
        mongoTemplate.findAll(Employee.class).sort(new BasicDBObject("hire_date", 1));

        // 3rd
        mongoTemplate.findAll(Employee.class).sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getHire_date() > o2.getHire_date());

        // and more...
    }
}
```

The solution might be pretty simple I guess, just like the query itself, but these are my first steps on that kind of ground. Thank you in advance for any help on this one.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: didn't have time to try it out unfortunately, I'll check later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "hire_date"),
    limit(10)
).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: yes, it helped :) but there is one weird behaviour - it wouldn't let me use `allowDiskUse` when I tried to write it by myself but when I copy-pased your answer, it worked

Comment: let me know why are we using `allowDiskUsage` here?

Comment: thank you. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/37805720/7975771 answer has clear explanation. Let me know if you have any doubts. I will try my best to sort it out

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below.

1. You need a query part

```
//As you need to match all
Query query = new Query()
```

2. You need to add sorting option

```
//You need to use Sort class with sorting order, field name to be used for sorting
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "hire_date"));
```

3. You need to add pagination option

```
final Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
query.with(pageableRequest);
```

4. You need to add a model

```
mongoTemplate(query, Employee.class)
```

[Sample refer](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb)

[Another useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521009/spring-mongodb-query-sorting/57718368)